# Trick for evaluating integrals over the whole real line (possible alternative derivation of gamma function?)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the integral,

$$ I_n= \int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n(x) dx \tag{1}$$

Where, $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, x \leq 0 \\ 
x^n e^{-x} , x > 0 \end{cases}$$

An interesting property of the integral is that, we can shift it by any amount $\epsilon$ and the value should be same since we would still be integrating over the same domain :

$$I_n = \int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n(x+ \epsilon)  dx \tag{2}$$

Substracting (1) and (2),

$$ 0 = \int_{\Bbb{R}} \left[ f_n(x+ \epsilon) - f_n(x) \right] dx$$

Divide both side by $\epsilon$ and sending $\epsilon \to 0 $, we have:

$$ 0 =\int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n'(x) dx$$

For $n>1$ , the function is differentiable at $x=0$, and hence:

$$ \int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n'(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1} e^{-x} - x^n e^{-x} dx =0$$

Using (1), we have:

$$ n I_{n-1} = I_n$$

By finding $I_1$, we can solve the above recurrence relation which leads to $I_n = n!$.

---

1. Is there a name for the method I've used here?
2. Are there other integrals where this method would be helpful in evaluating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)dx$ converges$$0=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{g(x+\epsilon)-g(x)}{\epsilon}dx\stackrel{!}{=}\int_{\Bbb R}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{g(x+\epsilon)-g(x)}{\epsilon}dx=\int_{\Bbb R}g^\prime(x)dx$$assumes the integration operator commutes with the limit operator, while$$\int_{\Bbb R}g^\prime(x)dx\stackrel{!}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)-\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)$$assumes the limits exist. For $g=f_n$, your strategy is the top approach and the usual strategy is the bottom one (and I leave it to you to explain why both strategies' assumptions hold), but both note $f_n^\prime=nf_{n-1}-f_n$. I think that answers part $2$. To address part $1$, I think all that would be named is theorems that justify the aforementioned operator exchange (six are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations#List_of_related_theorems)).